# Cycle through an int array and the use of modulo within it

Tags: java, arrays, modulo

I need to implement a method that returns the alternating sum of all elements with odd indexes minus the sum of all elements with even indexes. The total sum returned should be `-1`. `1 - 4 + 9 - 16 + 9 = -1`.

Here is my code:

```
public class Arrays
{
public static void main(String[] args){

    int [] data = {1 ,4, 9, 16, 9};

    oddAndEven(data);
}

public static int[] oddAndEven(int[] data){
    int sum = 0;
    int sumA = 0;
    int index = data.length;
    for(int i:data){
    if(index % sumA == 1){
            sum = sum-i;
        }
    else{
        sum = sum+i;
    }
}
    System.out.println(sum);
    return sum;
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong please?

This is a class session, so forgive my basic code and errors.

Comment: So what problem are you having? Actually you didn't ask any question at all/.

Comment: Just a couple of points already - why return sum, when you are printing it out in your method? It's not doing anything (not to mention it's an int, not an int[]. Also, your if statement will fail. You haven't changed the size of sumA, so you are dividing by 0 (which will destroy the world).

Comment: LOL!! Apologies. Basically, I need to cycle through the array one index at a time, determine whether its odd or even so that I know whether to add or subtract with that particular index.
I thought that I had to return sum as it is being called from the main method?
I was just looking for advice on my code, apart from it being awful...

Comment: This sounds like a straightforward iteration task (and ***not*** with enhanced for-loop). Were you instructed to use modulus?

Comment: No, was not instructed to use modulus but I thought you had to use modulus to determine odd and even numbers / indexes?

Comment: What do you mean by adding/subtracting to next index in statement...do you need to return sum..or array with adding/subtracting values to next index

Comment: I just need to return the sum of  the indexes.

Comment: @PrimalScientist: Do you mean take element 0, add to element 1, subtract total from element 2, add total to element 3 etc? If so, amend your question to say it and make it clearer

Comment: Amended question as requested. Sorry for making it confusing at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [] data = {1 ,4, 9, 16, 9};
    oddAndEven(data);
}

public static void oddAndEven(int[] data) {

    int total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        if (i%2==0)
            total = total + data[i];
        else
            total = total - data[i];
    }

    System.out.println(total);
}
```

1. I've gotten rid of the return in the method and changed it to void (as you are printing out the result within it, so there is no need to return it.
2. You don't need the two different sum values, or the length of the array stored.
3. The total value is used and set to 0. The for loop then goes through the length of the array. The %2 divides the number by 2 and determines the remainder. So for the first loop, it will calculate 0/2 and work out the remainder (obviously 0). As it ==0, the first if statement in the for loop is executed (adding the numbers).
   The second time through, it calculates 1/2, which is 0 with 1 remaining - so the else statement is executed and so on.
4. Additionally, note how I've gotten rid of the braces around the if and else statements. As long as these statements are a single line, the braces aren't needed - taking the out tends to make the program easier to read (in my opinion). Obviously, if more than one line were needed under them, the braces need to be readded.

Comment: I just keep making so many stupid mistakes. Just cant get my head around it sometimes, just waiting for that eureka moment, if it ever comes...
Thank you all though.

Comment: With regards to the braces - noted. Thanks.

Comment: @PrimalScientist: It might seem like I knew a lot posting that, but I only started a conversion course in September. If you asked me about lists or maps or anything like that I'd be lost. But you start to pick it up more and more. My advice? Check out these forums a lot and watch the answers that people give. This is a truly amazing forum for discussion and learning.

Comment: Totally agree. Stackoverflow is the wikipedia of programming. Truly amazing.
What I have also noted, everyone just helps big time. Really helpful. I owe everyone a drink! =]

Comment: @PrimalScientist: As this is going off topic, join me in the SO chatroom - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24672/convo-room

Answer (score 1):

What about this ?

```
public class ArrayMeNow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] data = {1 ,4, 9, 16, 9};

        int result = oddAndEven(data);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static int oddAndEven(int[] data) {
        int multiplier = 1;
        int result = 0;

        for(int v:data){
            result += v * multiplier;
            multiplier *= -1;
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int oddAndEven(int[] data) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            sum = sum - data[i];
        } else {
            sum = sum + data[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Many thanks for your help. Sorry for making it confusing at first.

Answer (score 1):

`for(int i:data)` doesn't change the value of index. And `sumA` is supposed to be `2`.

Change your for-loop to something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  if (i % 2 == 1)
    sum -= data[i];
  else
    sum += data[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to return `sum` which is of type `int` **NOT** `int[]`. Here is another way to do it.

```
public static int doAlternateAddSubOn(int[] array) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        // When index 'i' is Even, the position is Odd
        sum = (i%2==0) ? sum+array[i] : sum-array[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```